# Href to other html file doesn't work in google chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, href

I have the following simple html file with inside the body only 1 link to another html file in the same folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 

    <div>       
        <a href="homepage.html">Homepage</a>        
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open the html page in mozilla firefox and click the link, I correctly go to homepage.html. But when I do the same in google Chrome, I get an "error loading page". If I right-click the link and do "open in new tab" google chrome correctly goes to homepahe.html. Both files are in the same folder and their naming is correct. Now, if I remove the imported jquery scripts in the header section, the link works with normal click in google chrome

Obviously, it cannot be jquery wrecks google chrome. So what is wrong?

My html files are not on a server, but local. There used to be a bug with that (http://doeswhat.com/2011/03/08/jquery-mobile-error-loading-page/) but on the page it says its fixed now. I don't know how to host files on a server.

Comment: What URL does it go to in Chrome?

Comment: What does this question have to do with jQuery other than the fact you're loading jQuery on the page?

Comment: Use the full URL http://doeswhat.com/2011/03/08/jquery-mobile-error-loading-page/

Comment: If you remove the second jQuery mobile script, it works, so that's your problem!

Comment: Have you tried, "/homepage.html"?  Is the homepage in the same directory with this html?

Comment: Yes, they're in the same space and adding the / doesn't work. Please note that it works in firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Try adding rel="external" to your link. This should help with the issue and allow you to not add the full path.
Sincerely,
Thakur Saksham Chauhan

Comment: This worked. Can you explain what exactly this does and why it is needed for only some browsers?

Comment: rel="external" does nothing except notify the browser to open a new window, like target="_blank". The only difference is that rel="external" is xhtml valid, and target="_blank" is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding rel="external" to your link.  This should help with the issue and allow you to not add the full path.